# Was Dan Hedaya's General killed or "pithed" by the xeno?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-resurrection-1997

I know in *Alien* (first movie) extensive cocooning scenes were cut, and these scenes show I believe at least Dallas and Brett cocooned, even though with the cuts one could easily conclude that the creature had in fact killed them both. I do think the xeno may have killed Parker because Parker was trying to fight it.

In *Aliens*, killing during battle or to protect queen/eggs seems to be a reason to kill, though I believe at least Burke ended up cocooned.

In *Resurrection*, the General is apparently killed by a xeno who sinks its projecting jaws into the back of his head, but it occurred to me this was a very deliberate sort of "bite" -- perhaps meant to disable/paralyze the host but not kill (and I wonder if having this character dispatched in this unusual manner was indeed meant to convey this idea). I am not sure we know of anyone killed at least initially in Resurrection.

So is there any indication (such as cut scenes or commentary) indicating whether the General was killed immediately, and if so why, given he presented no threat to the xenomorphs?

Comment: Sources?  You think a number of things here, but is there any evidence they're not just headcanon?

Comment: This seems to have a lot of context and also seems to be asking more than one question. To keep the question open, maybe it's best you trim down the context and narrow this down to a single, clear question?

Comment: I agree with Andres F.; the two incidental questions about Parker and Lambert serve only to confuse this question.

Comment: Tried to salvage the question by trimming it down, hopefully the OP will agree with this change.

Comment: @AndresF. - Yes, very much improved

Comment: @releasabe please don't ask about reasons for closure in the body of your question; instead use actual comments or take it to meta. In my opinion, the question should not be closed since it's now clear and direct; but sometimes the community just won't like a question, and that's that. Let's wait and see.

Comment: I can answer this trimmed down version of the question with evidence (specifically, the part about whether General Perez was killed or not), so I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the audio commentary for the film, the director, Jean-Pierre Jeunet, indicated that Dan Hedaya's character, [General Martin Perez](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Martin_Per%C3%A9z), died in the scene you're asking about (which occurs at about 40 minutes into the runtime).

> JEAN-PIERRE JEUNET: **So there is a story about the death of General Perez, because, at the beginning, it was a big deal. He was sucked by a hole on the spaceship. And in fact, I kept the idea for the ending with the newborn, the new alien. And I proposed to the studio a very cheap death for General Perez - and I love this scene - but the studio didn't like it and they wanted to cut it. And by luck, I proposed to Tom Ruffman, I said: "OK. You have to ask the audience for the next test screening." And it was in Las Vegas, if you remember. And by luck, the audience loved this scene on the screening, and they saved my life, they saved this scene. And we kept it because the audience is right.**
>
> HERVÉ SCHNEID: And the shot was quite funny afterwards - we cut it here - but afterwards he kept looking at his brain and fainting in a very very humorous way. That was very nice.
>
> JEAN-PIERRE JEUNET: It's a little bit too funny. But I love that. I remember, Sigourney didn't like it too.
>
> <sub>*Alien: Resurrection* (1997) - audio commentary by director Jean-Pierre Jeunet and editor Hervé Schneid</sub>

As alluded to in the quote above, the scene in question was actually the second version of Perez's death that the filmmakers came up with; in an [earlier draft of the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/alien-resurrection-1997.pdf), he was killed by being sucked through a window into space. They ended up using the window idea for the [Newborn](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Newborn)'s death scene, so Jeunet came up with an alternate death for Perez.

> FATHER: Warning. Potential hullbreach. Clear sector.
>
> **The blood eats a pinhole in the window** -- the nearest soldier is sucked back against the  window -- he SCREAMS as he is sucked through a hole no bigger than his fist.
>
> Still men are falling over each other, Perez herding them out. **A huge CRACKING sound, and Perez shuts his eyes.**
>
> **The window EXPLODES outward, the air blowing everything into space. Debris, vehicles, men, all tangled and dead as they are blown out into the black.**
>
> <sub>*Alien: Resurrection* (1997) - script by Joss Whedon - optional 2nd revision - July 22, 1996</sub>

The commentary doesn't clarify *why* Perez was killed, just that he *was* killed.

Comment: +1 Interesting about the alternate scene. I think ultimately the audience was *wrong* -- I side with Sigourney in thinking the scene is stupid. In fact, I strongly dislike all of the movie. It's odd because I really like Jeunet's other movies, but in this setting it's like he forgot he was making an Aliens movie and he was directing some sort of dark fantasy comedy, like The City of Lost Children. Just my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 4):

The film's [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_Resurrection_(novel)) is emphatic about the fact that he's dead.

> He watched the rigid, fanged tongue as it exploded from the monster’s mouth and realized, rather than felt, it slam into the back of his skull. The strike was so sharp, so sudden, so precise, that he didn’t have a chance to feel the pain, feel **the killing blow**. He didn’t even have time to react.
> The hand resting on his gun butt went slack, useless, and there was no longer any sensation on that side. Dazed by a turn of events too extreme and sudden for him to comprehend, Perez touched the back of his head with his other hand, the one he could still use. He came away with a palm full of blood and tissue and dimly recognized it as his own brain matter.
>
> Then his body finally reacted, shutting down all at once like a machine whose power source had been all too abruptly terminated.
> As Perez collapsed bonelessly to the floor, his murderer followed him to the ground, mantling its prey for its own purposes. There was no one left to salute the general or even acknowledge that **he’d just made the supreme sacrifice for his country and the deadly project he’d so firmly believed in.**

The suggestion of why is left unspoken, but at the time of his death he was armed and dangerous, and possibly seen as a threat to the xenos, or just a food source.